# GET & Command - Incorrect

Tags: php, get

I'm trying to make the command but I get an error..

*URL Link:*

http://www.site.com/page?Channel=EM

Datas.php

```
   $EM_URL = "http://site.com/live/em...."
```

PageView.php

```
      <? echo '$ ?><?php print $_GET['Channel']; print "_URL"; ?><?php '; ?>
```

**Screen:**

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Where the error am I doing?

Comment: Use a syntax highlighter.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: `<?php $var = $_GET['Channel'] . '_URL';
echo($$var); ?>`

I really doubt if getting name of the variable from outside (`$_GET[]`) is a good programming practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, what You're trying to do - to get part of the variables name from the URL (`$_GET[]`). In this case You should do something like this:

```
<?php 
    $var = $_GET['Channel'] . '_URL';
    echo($$var);
?>
```

NOTE:
I really doubt it's a good practice for security reasons. You should strip the input at least. Or use `switch..case` blocks for all defined possible input variables.

Reference: 2nd example in [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?php echo '$'; ?>
  <?php print $_GET['Channel']; print "_URL"; ?>
  <?php print "'"; ?>
```