# "file_get_contents" in PHP file error

Tags: php, function, file-get-contents, var

Address;

```
   http://www.site.com/page?Channel=CNNi
```

**ChannelDatas.php**

*ChannelDatas.php include (in) _VideoPanel.php*

```
   $CNNi_JSON = 'http://edition.cnn.com/CNNI/schedules/json/CSI.NA.html';
```

**codes in "_VideoPanel.php"**

```
   74  <?php
   75  $DosyaJson = $var = $_GET['Channel'] . '_JSON'; print($$var);
   76  $html = file_get_contents($DosyaJson);

   ....

   ?>
```

**I get an error like this:**

```
   http://edition.cnn.com/CNNI/schedules/json/CSI.NA.html
   Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in /****/_VideoPanel.php on line 76

   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /****/_VideoPanel.php on line 87
```

I make a mistake in $DosyaJson - Where is the error?

**Graphic Exp:**

[image: http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/2438/3bse.png]

p.s:

```
$var = $_GET['Channel'] . '_JSON'; print($$var);
```

> [GET & Command - Incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388426/get-command-incorrect)

Comment: What does `var_dump($DosyaJson);` output? Also, why are you using variable variables?

Comment: What? You don't need `$$var` to get an input via `GET`. Could you please edit the question and state what ***exactly*** are you trying to do? Your code doesn't make sense, to be honest.

Comment: @AmalMurali What would you suggest me to do? - (I updated this question)

Comment: Try and explain what your app must do.  As the question is now I can't even make out what you are asking.

Comment: @Saracoglu: I still can't make out what are you trying to do? Please explain.

Comment: @AmalMurali graphical explanation: http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/2438/3bse.png

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have faulty markup,

```
<?php
   $DosyaJson = $var = $_GET['Channel'] . '_JSON'; print($$var);
   $html = file_get_contents($DosyaJson);
```

should be

```
<?php
    $var = $_GET['Channel']; //mind capital letters to, case sensitivity in linux.
    $DosyaJson = $var .'_JSON'; //Appending the string in a correct way.
    print_r($DosyaJson);
    $html = file_get_contents($DosyaJson);
```

This code is alot more readable to us aswell as to you, and you cannot define a variable while defining another variable.

e.g.

```
$var = $var2 = '3';
```

Is invalid markup.
You should always first create the variable, and append it later in your code.

This will improve your readability and will help you locate errors more easily.

It could also be a problem with the $_GET['Channel'] global.
If this is not set it will throw an undefined index erorr, which is probably messing up your code.

You should always check  if `$_POST` or `$_GET` variables are set by using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)